# Merging strings and constants causing scope errors

Tags: string, code-optimization

I'm getting a few errors when merging strings with constants.

Here's the pertinent code...

```
#define STATION_ID ABC123
#define STATION_PASS XYZ987

void loop(){
    String path = "/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?ID="+STATION_ID+"&PASSWORD="+STATION_PASS+"&dateutc=now&tempf="+celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature)+"&humidity="+String(humidity)+"&action=updateraw";
}
```

And then the errors...

```
weather.cpp:15:20: error: 'ABC123' was not declared in this scope
weather.cpp:64:66: note: in expansion of macro 'STATION_ID'

weather.cpp:16:22: error: 'XYZ987' was not declared in this scope
weather.cpp:64:90: note: in expansion of macro 'STATION_PASS'
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe? Not sure, but give this a try.

```
#define STATION_ID "ABC123"
#define STATION_PASS "XYZ987"
```

Answer (score 1):

Further optimization is:

```
#define STATION_ID "ABC123"
#define STATION_PASS "XYZ987"

void loop(){
    String path = "/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?ID=" STATION_ID "&PASSWORD=" STATION_PASS "&dateutc=now&tempf="+celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature)+"&humidity="+String(humidity)+"&action=updateraw";
}
```

This will remove some intermediate String variables in the expression, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That is just so wrong on so many levels.

Firstly, you should really not use `String`, especially not for constants.

Secondly, you do not need to manually concatenate string constants at all.

Thirdly, there is very rarely ever any need to concatenate things together into a single string before using them. Instead you can in general send individual parts separately:

```
#define STATION_ID "ABC123"
#define STATION_PASS "XYZ987"

client.print(F("/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?ID=" 
               STATION_ID 
               "&PASSWORD=" 
               STATION_PASS 
               "&dateutc=now&tempf="));
client.print(celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature));
client.print(F("&humidity="));
client.print(humidity);
client.print(F("&action=updateraw\r\n"));
```

By having multiple string constants next to each other (such as `"string one " "string two"`) the compiler will automatically join them together (into `"string one string two"`) for you. No plus, no comma, no nothing - just place them next to each other. And always use `F()` for string constants.

Comment: Calm down @Majenko, did you see this? `Here's the pertinent code...` I think he just gave an example. I think this: `That is just so wrong on so many levels.` is a little rude

Comment: You may think it's rude, but that doesn't stop it being completely true. It is so very very very wrong. On soooo many levels.